# Derive and validate a probability using a causal diagram

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, bayesian-network, marginal-distribution, causal-diagram

Given a causal diagram and the conditional probabilities for every adjacent node, I want to calculate a specific probability in two ways - let's call them the "simple" and "alternate" decompositions - but the reconciliation fails.

Can you help me identify if there's an error in the simple decomp and/or how to get the same result from the alternate decomp?

The probability I want is $p(O_p|E_{non})$.

Simple decomp gives me
$p(O_p|E_{non})=p(O_p|E_{non},C_{l},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{l}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)$

I provide all the context below.

#### Causal diagram

I have this causal diagram where all random variables are binary and take the following values.

O($\Omega)$={p,r}

D($\Omega)$={cons,b2b}

E($\Omega)$={b,non}

C($\Omega)$={ex,l}

[image]

I know the conditional probabilities for adjacent nodes, e.g. I know $P(O|E,D,C)$. Importantly, $p(O_p|D_d,C_{ex},E_{non})=0$ and $p(O_p|D_d,C_l,E_b)=0$ i.e. in words, O is never equal to p if E is "non" and C is "ex", or if E is "b" and C is "l" -- no matter what D is.

To rephrase my question - I am interested in marginal probabilities, in particular $P(O_p|E_{non})$. I have calculated it and I want to double check using another decomposition, but I am stuck, so I can't finish the reconciliation.

I have found that

$P(O_p|E_{non})=p(O_p|E_{non},C_{l},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{l}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)$

Which I can evaluate because it only includes conditional probabilities that I know. I got this expression using a simple decomposition, which I am trying to validate using another decomposition.

#### Simple decomposition

Just "marginalise out" the other variables that O depends on:

$p(O_p | E_{non})$
=$p(O_p,D_{cons},C_{ex}|E_{non})+p(O_p,D_{cons},C_l|E_{non})+p(O_p,D_{b2b},C_{ex}|E_{non})+p(O_p,D_{b2b},C_l|E_{non})$

From the causal diagram, C and E are independent. I take C out of the joint and using the independance assumption, it simplifies as:

= $p(O_p,D_{cons}|E_{non},C_{ex}) \times p(C_{ex})+p(O_p,D_{cons}|E_{non},C_{l}) \times p(C_{l})+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_{ex}) \times p(C_{ex})+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l)$

(now take D out of the joint)

= $p(O_p|E_{non},C_{ex},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{ex}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_{ex}) +p(O_p|E_{non},C_{l},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{l}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)+p(O_p|E_{non},C_{ex},D_{b2b}) \times p(C_{ex})\times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_{ex})+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)$

And $p(O_p|D_{cons},C_{ex},E_{non})=0$, so

=$p(O_p|E_{non},C_{l},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{l}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)$

Ok, done.

#### Alternative decomposition

I start by "marginalising out" using D (I can give more context about why I am interested in this particular decomp, but in any case, it should work).

$p(O_p | E_{non})$
=$p(O_p,D_{cons}|E_{non})+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non})$
=$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{cons})\times p(D_{cons}|E_{non}) +p(O_p|E_{non}, D_{b2b})\times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non})$

Intermediate step - expand $p(O|E,D)$:

$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{d})$
=$p(O_p,C_{ex}|E_{non},D_{d})+p(O_p,C_l|E_{non},D_{d})$
=$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{d},C_{ex})\times p(C_{ex}|D_{d},E_{non})+p(O_p|E_{non},D_{d},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_d)$

But $p(O_p|D_d,C_{ex},E_{non})=0$, so

$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{d})$
=$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{d},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_d)$

And briging it back into the main expression:

$p(O_p | E_{non})$
=$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{cons},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_{cons}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non}) + p(O_p|E_{non},D_{b2b},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_{b2b}) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non})$

Second intermediate step - expand $p(D|E)$

$p(D_d|E_{non})=p(D_d,C_{ex}|E_{non})+p(D_d,C_l|E_{non})=p(D_d|E_{non},C_{ex})\times p(C_{ex})+p(D_d|E_{non},C_l)\times p(C_l)$

Bringing it back into the main expression:

$p(O_p | E_{non})$
=$p(O_p|E_{non},D_{cons},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_{cons}) \times \{ p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_{ex})\times p(C_{ex})+p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)\times p(C_l) \}  + p(O_p|E_{non},D_{b2b},C_l)\times p(C_l|E_{non},D_{b2b}) \times \{ p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_{ex})\times p(C_{ex})+p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)\times p(C_l) \}$

I don't know how to take this expression further and get the same result derived above,
$p(O_p|E_{non},C_{l},D_{cons}) \times p(C_{l}) \times p(D_{cons}|E_{non},C_l)+p(O_p,D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l) \times p(C_l) \times p(D_{b2b}|E_{non},C_l)$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Summarised the problem at the top of the post.